# How to fix Timer drifting in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I built a timer to act as a clock that pings once every second and output the timestamp:

```
Private WithEvents Timer1Sec As New System.Timers.Timer
Private NumberPings As Integer
Private LastPingTime As Date
Private Duration As Integer = 1000 'in milliseconds

Private Sub StartTimer()
    Timer1Sec.AutoReset = True
    Timer1Sec.Interval = Duration

    NumberPings = 0
    LastPingTime = Now()
    Console.WriteLine(LastPingTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") & " Ping(Start)")
    Timer1Sec.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Ping() Handles Timer1Sec.Elapsed
    NumberPings += 1
    Dim TimeNow As Date = Now()
    Dim TimeBewteen As TimeSpan = TimeNow - LastPingTime
    Dim TimeDrift As Double = Math.Round(TimeBewteen.TotalMilliseconds - Duration, 4)
    Console.WriteLine(TimeNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") & " Ping(" & NumberPings & ") MilSecDrift(" & TimeDrift & ")")
    LastPingTime = TimeNow
End Sub
```

Here is a typical sample of the output for the first 10 seconds:

```
12:02:12:091 Ping(Start)
12:02:13:122 Ping(1) MilSecDrift(31.1539)
12:02:14:123 Ping(2) MilSecDrift(0.648)
12:02:15:124 Ping(3) MilSecDrift(0.6483)
12:02:16:126 Ping(4) MilSecDrift(2.1463)
12:02:17:126 Ping(5) MilSecDrift(0.1452)
12:02:18:127 Ping(6) MilSecDrift(0.6468)
12:02:19:127 Ping(7) MilSecDrift(0.1476)
12:02:20:128 Ping(8) MilSecDrift(0.6449)
12:02:21:128 Ping(9) MilSecDrift(0.6527)
12:02:22:128 Ping(10) MilSecDrift(0.1499)
```

As you can see, the ping does not occur at exactly every 1000 milliseconds. Instead, it appears to be going every 1000.15 to 1001.5 milliseconds, causing it to drift by as much as 5+ milliseconds for each 10-second period. This drift adds up over time and causes the clock to become inaccurate very quickly.

How do I get the timer to automatically correct for the drifting that occurs with each consecutive ping? Or should I instead use something other than System.Timer?

Edit:
I am only looking for the `Timer1Sec.Elapsed` event to fire at 1000ms on average. For example, it should fire 1 million times if I ran it for 1 million seconds. But instead, because of the drift, it currently will fire only about 999,000 times during the million seconds.

Comment: Timer is not suitable to implement a clock.  For one, it can never get exactly 1000 msec, only 65 * 15.6 = 1014 msec.  You'll be closer when you ask for 64 * 15.6 = 998 msec.  For another there is always an unpredictable delay to get code running that depends on what else is running on the machine.  Use a real clock to measure elapsed time, DateTime.UtcNow or Environment.TickCount.  Or Stopwatch for short intervals.

Comment: @HansPassant Your suggestion would improve the timestamp, but what I really need is for the events from `Timer1Sec.Elapsed` to fire at exactly 1000 milliseconds on average (and not drift ahead over time).

Comment: Like Hans already wrote, the most non-3rd party tool to get a high precision timer is to use [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

Comment: Why do you need the events to occur at such a specific interval?

Comment: @Jason What I need is something that generates events and corrects itself automatically for any drift. Using the example I provided of a 1-second timer, after 1 million seconds it theoretically would have raised the event only 999,000 times because of how it drifts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") has some very powerful schedulers that might help.

Here's an implementation of a timer that, on average, avoids drift:

```
Dim started = DateTimeOffset.Now
Dim reschedule As Func(Of IScheduler, Long, IDisposable) = Nothing
reschedule = Function(s, n)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(started).TotalMilliseconds)
    Return s.Schedule(n + 1, started.AddSeconds(n), reschedule)
End Function
Dim subscription = Scheduler.Default.Schedule(2, started.AddSeconds(1.0), reschedule)
```

With it I get this output:

```
1002.8448
2010.5127
3010.3938
4007.4535
5009.4021
6006.5253
7011.6813
8010.7322
9009.4839
10008.4011
11007.4128
12010.4043
13008.677
14007.8758
15010.4403
16006.6366
17010.2003
18010.5
19008.4129
```

You can see it has a little overhead past the 1 second point, but it continually attempts to adjust.

Look for the classes in the `System.Reactive.Concurrency` namespace.

To stop the timer simply call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about driving up your CPU, you could try doing something like this:

```
    Dim tickInterval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    Dim timeToTick = DateTime.Now + tickInterval

    While True
        While DateTime.Now < timeToTick
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeToTick - DateTime.Now)
        End While
        timeToTick += tickInterval
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.FFF"))
    End While
```